# Pgfplots error bars with different lengths in pos/neg

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to specify different error magnitudes for the pos/neg directions in a PGFplots plot?

```
\addplot[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] coordinates{
        (1,0.0319)+-(0,0.0035)
        (2,0.0952)+-(0,0.0115)
        (3,0.1798)+-(0,0.0188)
        (4,0.2856)+-(0,0.0287)};
```

In the sample code above I have four points with y error. The error, however, can only be specified using a single scalar and is the same is both directions. Is it possible to specify both positive and negative error bars?

I imagine this (which doesn't work):

```
 \addplot[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] coordinates{
        (1,0.0319)+-(0,-0.0035 and 0.0035)
        (2,0.0952)+-(0,-0.0120 and 0.0142)
        (3,0.1798)+-(0,-0.0188 and 0.0176)
        (4,0.2856)+-(0,-0.0287 and 0.0250)};
```

The reason I am doing this is to get an effect similar to a box-plot where I can show one quartile above and below the mean line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The syntax `+-` defines *symmetric* values; for *asymmetric* values, you can use `-=` and `+=`.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit] coordinates{
        (1,0.0319) += (0,-0.0035) -=(0,-0.0135)
        (2,0.0952) +=(0,-0.0090) -=(0,-0.0192)
        (3,0.1798) +=(0,-0.0188) -= (0,-0.0376)
        (4,0.2856) +=(0,-0.0287) -= (0,-0.0120)
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```